# How to get Input type="text" in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is i want to insert a value in a textbox but refer the element by their attribute value as you can see "text" but i am unable to insert a value in

```
<html>
 <body>
 <p id="p" align="justify">HI</p>
 <input type="text"  placeholder="Enter age" id="text"/>
 <input type="button" onclick="z()" value="Submit"/>
 <script>
    function z()
    {
    var age=document.getElementsByTagName("text").value;
    if(age<=18)
     {
     alert("age is less Than and equal to 18 Year")
     }
     else
     {
 alert("age is more than 18 Year")
    }
   }
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

[image]

Comment: You can use document.getElementById('text')

Comment: "getElementsByTagName" returns array of all elements from this type (In your case - it will return empty arry, becayse the type of this tage is "input").  As whites11 said, You can use "getElementById" instead because you had set an ID to this element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [w3c documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp) :

> The getElementsByTagName() method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified tag name, as a NodeList object.

You cannot select by tag "text" as this is not a valid tag. Here a valid tag would be "input" or "p". If you still want to select by the type of your input, try [query selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: *You cannot select by tag "text" as this is not a valid tag.* nitpicking, but actually you can... If there is an HTMLUnknownElement `<text>` in the HTMLdocument, or a valid SVGTextElement in a SVGDocument, or other xml doc formats, it will be found by `getElementsByTagName('text')`.

Comment: Can you pls Explain The difference Between ElementsByName or ElementsByTagName or ElementsByTagNameNS

Comment: ElementsByName select using the name field of html element, ElementsByTagName select using the name of the tag, like "p" or "input" and ElementsByTagNameNS do the same but with a special parameter: the namespace. The namespace is a description of what can be found. For example if you want to match only XHTML element and not all HTML5 element you can use the namespace "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"

If you want to know more about namespaces, search for the concept of ontology in computer science.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is get element by tag name, "text" is not a tag name instead in your case the name of tag is "input". But instead of using tag name use id of tag to get that element. You have given id="text" to the element, so use getElementById("text").

Following is your code updated.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p id="p" align="justify">HI</p>
  <input type="text"  placeholder="Enter age" id="text"/>
  <input type="button" onclick="z()" value="Submit"/>
  <script>
    function z() {
      var age=document.getElementById("text").value;
      if(age<=18)
      {
        alert("age is less Than and equal to 18 Year")
      }
      else
     {
      alert("age is more than 18 Year")
     }
  }
   </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an id for the input field, so get it through document.getElementById and then analyze its value.

```js
 function z()
    {
    var age=document.getElementById("text").value;
    if(age<=18)
     {
     alert("age is less Than and equal to 18 Year")
     }
     else
     {
 alert("age is more than 18 Year")
    }
   }
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
 <p id="p" align="justify">HI</p>
 <input type="text"  placeholder="Enter age" id="text"/>
 <input type="button" onclick="z()" value="Submit"/>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it tells that you need little clarification & reading about using DOM in javascript.

What is `Tag` in `getElementsByTagName`?

1. `Tag` is something defined in html to tell what is the control. Example `<p>`, `<input>`, `<label>`,etc
2. `getElementsByTagName` method will fetch all elements of that `tag` and any operation on the result will be performed on  all of them.

To avoid this an `id` should be assigned to `html` elements and the `id` should be used in `JS` to get element and perform operations on it.

**Example**

```
var myObj = document.getElementById(‘ID_Og_Element’);
```

> Ref [getElementsByTagName W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp)